# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character α (U+3B1) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: bibtex, citing, input-encodings

When I compile the `.tex` file, I get the said error. It points out to `.bbl` file in the following line:

```
\bibitem{LIU20083883}
G.~Liu, T.~Nguyen-Thoi, K.~Lam,
  \href{http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782508001199}{A
  novel alpha finite element method (αfem) for exact solution to mechanics
  problems using triangular and tetrahedral elements}, Computer Methods in
  Applied Mechanics and Engineering 197~(45) (2008) 3883 -- 3897.
\newblock \href {http://dx.doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cma.2008.03.011}
  {\path{doi:https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cma.2008.03.011}}.
\newline\urlprefix\url{http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782508001199}
```

How to overcome this issue? This error popped up in the new version of TeXStudio. I didn't see this while I compiled in the older version.

Comment: Consider using XeLaTeX if your publisher allows it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the `.bib` file to read `$\alpha$FEM`, but there's a better method, namely loading `textalpha`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{LIU20083883,
title = "A novel alpha finite element method (α{FEM}) for exact solution to mechanics problems using triangular and tetrahedral elements",
journal = "Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering",
volume = "197",
number = "45",
pages = "3883-3897",
year = "2008",
issn = "0045-7825",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cma.2008.03.011",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782508001199",
author = "G.R. Liu and T. Nguyen-Thoi and K.Y. Lam",
keywords = "Numerical methods, Finite element method (FEM), Node-based smoothed finite element method (N-SFEM), Upper bound, Lower bound, Alpha finite element method (FEM)"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textalpha} % <--- Greek letters in text

\begin{document}

\cite{LIU20083883}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `.bib` file has to be slightly edited anyhow, because `αFEM` would result in

> αfem

in print (and we can see it in your printout). The uppercase letters should be kept, so they should be enclosed in braces:

```
title = "A novel alpha finite element method (α{FEM}) for exact [...]
```

Also

```
pages = "3883 -- 3897",
```

should better be

```
pages = "3883-3897",
```

Note: I downloaded the `.bib` entry from the [publisher's site](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782508001199?via%3Dihub).

Comment: This is amazingly useful, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the `α` in `(αfem)`. You can either change your .bib file and replace `(αfem)` with `($\alpha$fem)` or you can add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3B1}{\ensuremath{\alpha}}
```

to your preamble.

The `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` command will assign the code `\ensuremath{\alpha}` to the character  `3B1`.

Depending on the appearance you want to achieve for the α you can load the `upgreek` package and use `\ensuremath{\upalpha}` instead.

The `\ensuremath` guarantees that you can use `α` both in text and math mode.

Comment: This is a good place for `\ensuremath`.

Comment: @egreg Ouch, didn't realise that. Thanks :D